# Counting output appearances on screen

Tags: java

How to count number of occurrences when `System.out` prints something? In my example user input TR* and lets say program founds TRR; TRC; TRD, ect, but I can't manage to count number of outputs (3 in this example). I want to make so if 0 solutions are found to print out "No solutions found".

Any tips on how to make this work.

```
if (length == 3) {
    System.out.println("Possible solutions:");
    n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list3.size(); i++) {
        String s = (String) list3.get(i);
        if (s.matches(user_input))
            System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println("No solutions found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not incrementing `n` anywhere. How should it be `1` then? And shouldn't it be `if (n == 0)` if there are no solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
package stackoverflow.counting;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        list3.add("TRA");
        list3.add("XXX");

        int length = 3;
        String user_input = "TR.*";

        if (length == 3) {
            System.out.println("Possible solutions:");
            int n = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.size(); i++) {
                String s = list3.get(i);
                if (s.matches(user_input)) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    n++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(n);
            if (n == 0) {
                System.out.println("No solutions found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

> Possible solutions:
>   TRA
>   1

Please also note that TR* is probably not the kind of regular expression you need. Use TR.* instead.

Comment: The indentation of `n++;` is wrong. When you fix that, then you'll see that your code misses something.

Comment: already tried this and it doesnt work i get 1440 which is the lenght of my list

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach:

```
int countOfSystemPrintedOutput = 0;
if (length == 3) {
    System.out.println("Possible solutions:");
    for (String s : list3) {
        if(s.matches(user_input)){
            System.out.println(s);
            countOfSystemPrintedOutput++;
        }
    }

    if (countOfSystemPrintedOutput == 0) {
        System.out.println("No solutions found");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("System.out.println called " + countOfSystemPrintedOutput + "times");
    }
}
```